# MariaDB Galera performance with remote nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, mariadb, galera

I'm creating a 5 node MariaDB / Galera cluster, with 4 nodes sharing the same router in close physical proximity, and 5th node 6,000 miles away on a much slower connection.

My question is, will this affect performance for the entire cluster, or will this result in a 'lazy update' on the 5th node?

Answer (score 0):

Galera requires approval from all the other nodes.  You will like this requirement if the 4 nodes "in close physical proximity" are simultaneously wiped out by a hurricane/earthquake/etc.

Consider having the 5th not so far away.  Or, if it is just a readonly node, use Async Replication.

Since you are willing to have less than the maximum HA, consider MySQL's "Group Replication" or "InnoDB Cluster".  It only requires a majority of nodes to ACK the replication.  In your case it would COMMIT without reaching for the 5th, hence be faster.